# How to Display VS Code output window to side rather than below

Tags: visual-studio-code, fsi, ionide

In my VS Code set up I see the output/FSI frame below the main text editor pane like this:

[image]

whereas I would love it to appear to the right in the side-by-side view like it does on the images in this link: http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jwood/a-quick-look-at-f-in-visual-studio-code

Is there a config option I cannot find somewhere?

I tried Googling but drew a blank and cannot see anything obvious in the config options mentioned on the [vs code site page describing the config options](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userandworkspace)

Comment: Just got added. You can view the pull request on [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/36827). This feature is available on VS code insiders now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't believe you can detach/move the output windows in Visual Studio Code. You can move the side bar to the left/right side, but that's it. There is no config option, sorry.

You could try posting a feature request on the GitHub page: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode

EDIT: This was changed in VS Code 0.10.8, it was once on the side but was moved to the bottom. See this GitHub issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2806

Comment: Thanks for responding. I couldn't find any config option either but, looking at the screengrabs on the blog, this guy seems to have done it: http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jwood/a-quick-look-at-f-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: I believe in an older, previous version of Visual Studio Code the output window was on the right side. But it was moved at some point to be the bottom. - Edited with version it changed

Comment: Floating window support (to detach/move a tab to a separate window) is still a pending feature request: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10121

Answer (score 51):

[image: vs code snapshot]

as of version 1.51.1 right click in the right corner on the output panel. then select option 'move panel right'

Comment: yes, but you right-click on the tab bar itself, not where the arrow is pointing ( the arrow is backwards )

Comment: Wow, I searched for this for so long, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This feature is not available yet in VS Code. However as of today (March 30, 2017) it's on [6 months roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2806#issuecomment-290486762) so it should be done in a near feature.

Answer (score 6):

This feature is available from version 1.18.0+

Simply click this icon to dock to the right:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Just follow the steps mentioned:

In Visual Studio Code -

**View** Tab > **Appearance** > **Toggle Panel Position**

That's it.

Answer (score 5):

Your original link to the view your desire is obsolete, so it is a guess as to what you wanted.  But here is a demo of setting up a terminal/output look side-by-side.  It is a little tricky - you drag your `Outline` header over the `Terminal` header which will then allow you the option of putting it to the left or right of the Terminal:

[image: move Output to right of terminal]

Answer (score 2):

its easy. just right-click on the terminal, select 'move panel right' like in the image below and voila

[the image can be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zISs7.png)

Comment: please, explain more.

Answer (score 1):

Vertical Split:

From VS Code Menu bar:

```
View >> Appearance >> Move Panel Right
```

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.47.0 of VS Code (at the moment of posting this, the latest one) allows you to drag output (or any other panel tab, e.g. terminal) to the activity bar. This way you can obtain output to the side of the editor.
[image: Output window tab in the activity bar]

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on the panel of output section then select "Move panel left or right" as per your wish.
[here your can see the move panel left option.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fPw2.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Press **CTRL** + **SHIFT** + **P**
2. Select `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`
3. Insert (or change if it is there --search for it) the following config line:

```
    "workbench.panel.defaultLocation": "right",
```

4. Save file.

---

That will work for **new** workspaces. VS-Code saves your preferences for each folder you start it in. So, if you navigate to a folder you previously called VS-Code in (I mean, from the terminal), it will open the output panel in the same location it was the last time you have used VS-Code from the same location.
After making the change above, go to a new place, like `/opt` and start VS-Code there to make a test.